# How does Kylo Ren escape from his attack run on the Raddus hangar bay?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, kylo-ren

In *The Last Jedi*, Kylo Ren attacks The Raddus (the lead Rebel ship) by flying straight into the hangar bay and launching two missiles.

> He ends up destroying Tallie (Blue Leader) and most of the Rebel fighters, with Poe and BB8 just barely surviving.

**How does Kylo Ren escape this attack run?**

I have the "Visual Dictionary" and the "Incredible Cross-Sections" books for The Last Jedi, and they both seem to illustrate a "corridor" that fighters would depart from, or return to. I don't see any way for Kylo Ren to "escape" or "turn around" in that corridor.

What am I missing?

Comment: Having not seen the film for a while I'd assume he shot from a safe distance, slowed turned around, and legged it before the missiles hit their targets. Either that or the explosion really wasn't that big as Poe who was closer than Kylo, and unprotected, managed to survive it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the film's [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition) there was sufficient distance between him and the ship to simply turn away before hitting it.

> *Kylo banked his fighter — a prototype TIE Silencer with a night-black
>   hull — away from the ruin of the starfighter hangar, his wingmates
>   matching the maneuver.*

Answer (score 3):

As the commenter said, he shot missiles from a pretty good range; so he had a chance to turn around:

[image]

Comment: I assumed this was the case but having not scene the film for a while was unsure. It's probably worth noting about the explosion not having been too big if Poe was unharmed by it and BB-8 only got blown backwards too and he was a lot closer.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot still seen, not scene ;)

Comment: It's Hollywood, I'd say there's a much greater chance of him just flying through the explosion.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - there's unlikely to be the other side to fly to - the hangar only has an entrance tunnel, behind it is the ship innards